# How can I manipulate shapes in order to have similar results as in this 3D max scene?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, 3d-view, scale

What I mean by this is, after applying an array, or adding cuts to one mesh, being able to modify the hole thing by one vertex, continuosly and as easy as that

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you need is the **Mesh Deform** modifier:

- Create an object **A** and give it an *Array* modifier.
- Create a cube **B** and change its mesh so that it contains your object **A** like a cage
- In the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Display* > *Maximum Draw Type*, choose *Wire* so that this cube **B** stays transparent in *Solid* mode. And in the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Cycles Settings* > *Ray Visibility*, disable all the options so that it will be invisible in *Rendered* mode.
- Give your object **A** a *Mesh Deform* modifier. Choose **B** as the *Object*. Click *Bind*.

Now, **if you want to animate**:

- Select your object **B** and in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Shape Keys*, create one first shape key to save the basic shape of **B**, then create a second shape key and keep this second shape key selected.
- In *Edit* mode play with the shape of the **B** mesh. You can see that it deforms **A**.
- Now back in *Object* mode, play with the *Value* under the *Shape Keys* to change the shape of **A**.

And **if you don't want to animate**:

- Just change the shape of your object **B** in *Edit* mode, it will deform object **A**.

[image]